# How to match item in the list processed by ngFor with another list with ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Suppose there is a list like the one below.

```
items = [
  { id: 1,
    name: "one"
  },
  { id: 3,
    name: "thee"
  },
  { id: 5,
    name: "five"
  },
  { id: 6,
    name: "six"
  },
];

lists = [
  { id: 5,
    name: "five"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "nine"
  },
];
```

I want items to be displayed only when item is processed with ngFor and item id is included in lists with ngIf.
But I do not know how

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <p *ngIf = "How can I write it here?">
    {{ item.name }}
  <p>
<div>
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more how you want to use lists?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control) to check if an item is present in the array.

```
<p *ngIf="lists.some(e => e.id === item.id)">
```

`some` will return `true` when an element in the `lists` array with same `id` value as `item` is found.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter your `items` directly in the `*ngFor` by using a pipe.

In your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | yourFilter:lists">
  <p>
    {{ item.name }}
  <p>
<div>
```

And your pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'yourFilter'})
export class YourFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: object[], lists: object[]): object[] {
    return items.filter(item => {
      lists.some(e => e.id === item.id)
    });
  }
}
```